# Why is file-loader working for images and videos but not for audio file in my react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

When I require images and videos in my react app it picks it up and references it, but it doesn't do the same with my audio files. the audio HTML 5 doesn't play at all.

my component folder which has an entry point component called app.js resides in the same directory where an mp3 file called 'thisisnikes.mp3' resides...
my app.js looks like this

```
            import React from 'react';
            import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


            import { Header } from './Header';
            import { Dashboard } from './Dashboard.js';
            import { Uploader } from './Uploader';
            import { NotFound } from './NotFound';
            import { Storefront } from './Storefront';

            import './../css/normalize.css';
            import './../css/main-style.css';


            export class App extends React.Component {
                constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                    this.state = {
                        headerVisible: true
                    }
                    this.addHeader = this.addHeader.bind(this);
                    this.removeHeader = this.removeHeader.bind(this);
                }
                removeHeader() {
                    this.setState({
                        headerVisible: false
                    })
                }
                addHeader() {
                    this.setState({
                        headerVisible: true
                    })
                }
                render() {
                    return  (
                        <BrowserRouter >
                            <div>
                                    <div className='container-wrapper'>
                                    { this.state.headerVisible
                                    && <Header /> 
                                    }   
                                    <audio controls autoPlay src={require('./thisisnikes.mp3')}></audio>
                                    
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route exact path='/' render={ () => ( <Redirect to='/Dashboard' /> ) } />
                                        <Route path='/Dashboard' component={ Dashboard } />
                                        <Route path='/Upload' component={ Uploader } />
                                        <Route path='/:storename' render={ ({ match }) => ( <Storefront match={match} addHeader={this.addHeader} removeHeader={this.removeHeader} /> ) } />
                                        <Route strict component={NotFound} />
                                        
                                    </Switch>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </BrowserRouter>
                        );
                }
            };
```

I tried this with a images and also a mp4 file and it loaded it successfully but for some reason it won't locate the mp3 file, my console is not returning any errors either.

My webpack.config.js looks like this

```
            var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
            var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
                filename: 'index.html',
                inject: 'body'
            });

            module.exports = {
                entry: __dirname + '/app/index.js',
                module: {
                    loaders: [
                        {
                            test: /\.js$/,
                            exclude: /node_modules/,
                            loader:  'babel-loader'
                        },
                        { 
                            test: /\.css$/, 
                            loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
                        },
                        {
                            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|mp4)$/i,
                            use: 'file-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
                            use: 'file-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                output: {
                    filename: 'transformed.js',
                    path: __dirname + '/build'
                },
                devServer: {
              historyApiFallback: true
            },
                plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
            };
```

Comment: Did you try to move `require` from jsx?

Comment: @StanislavMayorov yes, unfortunately I also tried that